# Is there a sensible way to unzip the state monad?

Tags: haskell, random, state, monads

I'd like to have a function like:

```
unzipState :: (MonadState s m) => m (a, b) -> (m a, m b)
```

which would take a (stateful) computation that returns a tuple, and would return two (dependant) computations.

The difficulty is of course in that extracting values from one or the other computation should update the state in the other.

A useful (and motivating) application is the Random monad, expressed as

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2types #-}
import qualified System.Random as SR
import Control.Monad.State

type Random a = forall r. (State RandomGen r) => State r a
```

and let's say you have:

```
normal :: Random Double
-- implementation skipped

correlateWith :: Double -> Random (Double, Double) -> Random (Double, Double)
correlateWith rho w = do
                        (u, v) <- w
                        return $ (u, p * u + (1 - p * p) * v)
```

it would be quite natural to be able to write:

```
let x = normal
    y = normal
    (u, v) = unzipState $ correlateWith 0.5 $ liftM2 (,) x y
    ... now I am able to perform computation on u and v as correlated random variables
```

Is there a sensible way to do this ? I struggled a bit, but did not manage to get to anything. Hoogle was of no help either.

**edit**

Great answers have shown me my problem is ill-defined. Nevertheless, can someone explain me *why* the following implementation in python (which I believe to be correct, but have not tested much) cannot be translated in Haskell (with the magic of STrefs, closures and other things I admit I don't grasp ;-) ):

```
def unzipState(p):
    flist, glist = [], []
    def f(state):
        if not flist:
            (fvalue, gvalue), newstate = p(state)
            glist.insert(0, gvalue)
            return (fvalue, newstate)
        else:
            fvalue = flist.pop()
            return (fvalue, state)
    def g(state):
        if not glist:
            (fvalue, gvalue), newstate = p(state)
            flist.insert(0, fvalue)
            return (fvalue, newstate)
        else:
            gvalue = glist.pop()
            return (gvalue, state)
    return (f, g)
```

Not that I am saying that stateful code can be translated in Haskell, but I feel like understanding *why* and *when* (even on an example) it cannot be done would improve my understanding a lot.

**edit2**

Now it is crystal clear. The functons f and g are obviously not pure, as their output does not only depend on the value of state.

Thanks again !

Comment: Since you brought up the example of random-value generators: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000364; it's interface resembles the one you're seeking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *impossible* to construct a general function `unzipState` that does what you want, if only because you probably can't provide a formal specification for its intended effect. In other words, assume that you have implemented some function `unzipState`. How do you know that it's correct? You would have to prove that it satisfies certain laws/equations, but the trouble here is to find these laws in the first place.

While I think I understand what you want to do, the `Random` monad also makes it apparent why it cannot be done. To see that, you have to ditch the concrete implementation `type Random a = ...` and consider the abstract interpretation given by

> `v :: Random a` means that `v` is a **probability distribution** of values of type `a`

The "bind" operation `(>>=) :: Random a -> (a -> Random b) -> Random b` is simply a way to construct a new probability distribution from an old probability distribution.

Now, this means that `unzipState` simply returns a pair of probability distributions, which can be used to construct other probability distributions. The point is that while the `do` syntax looks very suggestive, but you **don't actually sample** random variables, you just calculate probability distributions. Random variables can be correlated, but probability distributions cannot.

Note that it is possible to create a different monad `RandomVariable a` that corresponds to random variables. However, you have to fix the sample space Ω in advance. The implementation is

```
type RandomVariable a = Ω -> a
```

---

If you want both random variables and the ability to enlarge the sample space automatically, you probably need two bind operations

```
bind1 :: Random Ω a -> (a -> Random Ω b) -> Random Ω b
bind2 :: Random Ω1 a -> (a -> Random Ω2 b) -> Random (Ω1,Ω2) b
```

and some dependent type magic to deal with the proliferation of products like `(Ω1,(Ω2,Ω3))`.

Comment: I don't think (Random a) can really be interpreted as probability distributions because in that case, you need to be able to define omega as a probalized space, which is quite difficult. Furthermore, it is not because that two objects of Random a have the same distribution that they are equal (take two u = uniform; v=uniform, you don' have u=v). A more humble interpretation is to understand it as realisations  (more specifically, as functions operating on realisations) of random variables, which should be isomorphic to streams, so I believe that the unzip operation is well-defined).

Comment: Nope. If `u = uniform :: Random A` and `v = uniform :: Random A`, then it is trivially true that `u = v = uniform`. Keep in mind that there are two different notions here: random variables derived from a sample space Ω, and collections of values of type `a` weighted with a probability (= probability distribution). Your `Random a` monad corresponds to the latter, not the former. It is equally possible to implement it as `Random a = [(a,Probability)]`. [I'm afraid it's a bit tricky to discuss this without a formalization of the `Random a` monad and the particular effect you are after.]

Comment: you are perfectly right on the equality point, I was confused. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on how you'd like this to work--since `correlateWith` operates on a tuple, what meaning would the correlated variables have independently? Say you do this:

```
let x = normal
    y = normal
    (u, v) = unzipState $ correlateWith 0.5 $ liftM2 (,) x y
in do u1 <- u
      v1 <- v
      u2 <- u
      u3 <- u
      -- etc...
```

What relationship should exist between `u1`, `u2`, and `u3`?

Also, a "random variable" like this can be converted into an infinite lazy stream in a straightforward fashion. What would the meaning of the following be?

```
let x = normal
    y = normal
    (u, v) = unzipState $ correlateWith 0.5 $ liftM2 (,) x y
in do vs <- generateStream v
      u1 <- u
      if someCondition u1 then u else return u1
      -- etc...
```

Because the number of values sampled from `u` changes based on `u1`, this seems to suggest that the non-monadic value bound to `vs` would retroactively depend somehow on `u1` as well, which sounds suspiciously like the sort of spooky action at a distance that Haskell avoids.

I would hazard a guess that what you're trying to accomplish can't simply be retrofitted on top of a simple PRNG state monad, but there may be other options.

Comment: I guess the semantics would be exactly the same as for Streams: data Stream a = a :< Stream a, for which unzip is defined the same way as for lists: foldstream f (x:<xs) = f x (foldStream f xs) and unzipStream = foldStream (\\(a,b) ~ (as, bs) -> (a:<as, b:<bs)). In your first example, (u1, u2) are correlated, and each consecutive "drawing" of u stores a corresponding value of a drawing of v which would be drawn if one would write v2 <- v etc...

Comment: in the previous comment, please read (u1, v1) are correlated instead of (u1, u2) are correlated.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of related stuff on Bayesian monads in Haskell. Here's one reference: http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/02/22/bayes-rule-and-drug-tests

See also "Purely functional lazy non-deterministic programming" available from this page: http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/

Edit: I also fail to see why you can't just give `correlateWith` the following type signature, and run it inside the do block directly rather than try to "push" the random state in within a let binding.
`correlateWith :: Double -> Random Double -> Random Double -> Random (Double, Double)`

Comment: It is interesting material, but can you point me how does it relate to my problem ?

Comment: It shows how to do actual probability monads, instead of just overloading random and failing.